# Getting the error 'Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT' when using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I'm fairly new to swift and have been playing around with `NSNotificationCenter` in a Playground. I'm getting the error:

> **Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT**

when using the `postNotificationName` function. I cannot figure out exactly why the issue is occurring, any pointers will be helpful!

```
let notificationKey = "rachel"

class FirstViewController {

    var sentNotificationLabel = "Nothing has been sent yet."

    func addObserver() {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateNotificationLabel", name: notificationKey, object: nil)
    }

    func notify() {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(notificationKey, object: self)
    }

    func updateNotificationLabel() {

        self.sentNotificationLabel = "Notification sent!"
    }
}



class SecondViewController {

    var notificationLabel = "I have not been notified yet."

    func addObserver() {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateNotificationLabel", name: notificationKey, object: nil)
    }

    func updateNotificationLabel() {

        self.notificationLabel = "I've been notified!"
    }

    deinit {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}


class ThirdViewController {

    var notificationLabel = "I have not been notified yet."

    func addObserver() {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateNotificationLabel", name: notificationKey, object: nil)
    }

    func updateNotificationLabel() {

        self.notificationLabel = "I've been notified too!"
    }

    deinit {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}



var firstView = FirstViewController()
print(firstView.sentNotificationLabel) // Nothing has been sent yet.
firstView.addObserver()
firstView.updateNotificationLabel()
firstView.notify() // ERROR 'Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT'
print(firstView.sentNotificationLabel) // Notification sent!

var secondView = SecondViewController()
print(secondView.notificationLabel)

var thirdView = ThirdViewController()
print(thirdView.notificationLabel)
```

Comment: Why are you calling `firstView.updateNotificationLabel()` before `firstView.notify()` if `notify()` calls `updateNotificationLabel()` through your notification?

Answer (score 0):

Try conforming the three classes to `NSObject`... You can't use NSNotificationCenter with purely swift objects.

IE: `class FirstViewController: NSObject {}`